# Determining whether a natural number has no "1"s in its ternary expansion, without direct calculation

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, cantor-set, ternary-expansion

I am considering a problem concerning Cantor set.

Here is my quesion:

> Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Is there any way other than direct calculation to determine
> whether $N$ has no "1" as digits in its ternary expansion?

Comment: What have you tried? Or what are your thoughts on a possible solution?

Comment: Question simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451327/number-of-1-in-the-ternary-expansion-of-a-p-frac3p-1-1p

Comment: The Cantor-set does not deal with natural numers , but with real number in the interval $[0,1]$. I strongly doubt that there is a direct general way to determine whether a given natural number has a $1$ in the base-$3$-system.

Comment: Another way to phrase the question: *Which natural numbers can be written as twice the sum of some powers of $3$?$*

Comment: For some $N$ there are $3^N$ numbers between $0$ and $3^N-1$. Between them, there are $2^N$ numbers which have no digit "1" in their ternary expression.